# Overvoltage from diode output

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, dc, power-electronics

I made such a circuit on the PCB to charge the 12 V battery.
Although the calculation is correct, the output voltage is 23 V instead of 15 V.
I found out that this is caused by the STTH1R02A diode.

It gave the same issue even though I used several different diodes.but when i remove the diode there is no problem
I mean this;

1. Why does a diode rise when it should drop 0.7 V?
2. What SMD diodes can I use that will give 0.7 V drop?

[image]

*Figure 1. Breadboard layout and PSU.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Circuit schematic.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Voltage measurement after diode.*

[[image]

*Figure 4. Voltage measurement with diode removed.*

Comment: You can't get 23 V (capital 'V' for volt) from a low-dropout regulator fed from a 16 V supply unless the 16 V supply is something like a full-wave rectified AC supply which would peak at \$16\sqrt 2\$ V. Can you [edit] your question to include the voltage readings between VIN - GND and VOUT - GND and OUT - GND?

Comment: An LDO followed by a diode can not boost the voltage higher than the input voltage to the LDO.  You have a measurement error, or some external voltage present that you haven't shown on your schematic. (Or your adapter isn't 16V DC).

Comment: Oh, and please explain what you mean by "excessive voltage **spike**".

Comment: I also tested it on the breadboard, it gives a higher voltage than the input voltage

Comment: @ transistor excuse me i don't know much about electronics i don't understand what you mean.
input voltage 16v dc voltage.
when i remove the diode the output voltage is 15.1v

Comment: (1) You should be able to understand my voltage reading requests. (2) Can you add in a sharp, cropped photo of your circuit layout?

Comment: Well, that circuit, when not connected to anything, does violate the minimum load current requirements. But it would not explain your 23V reading, so you need to tell where exactly was multimeter positive and negative leads connected, and was there any load after the diode. In some very high-impedance nodes after a diode, some external capacitive coupling could affect the reading - were you by any chance using a mains-powered multimeter, or handheld battery powered multimeter? Was the 16V supply coming from what kind of power supply, earth grounded or ungrounded? Isolated, floating?

Comment: @ transistor I uploaded a photo

Comment: I tried it with 16v dc wall adapter and lm2596 voltage reducer, same result.no load after diode

Comment: Sabri73, you need to do a better job inserting photos. Insert them in the right sequence, leave a blank line before and after and put captions on them so we can discuss them. I've cleaned it up for you.

Comment: @ transistör Thank you for editing the photos.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably an LDO regulator oscillation problem.

The DC voltmeter would be reading the oscillating output (AC) that has been rectified by the diode.

Comment: I removed the last diode and soldered another diode, this time it was 13v.
this time it gave lower voltage than expected